# I have a df[rn,rn1,rn2]. When rn is null, I want to generate random number and assign it to rn1,rn2

Tags: scala, pyspark

Df consists of these rows [rn,rn1,rn2].
The condition is,if rn is null,generate a random number between 0-1000 and then assign that value to rn1,rn2.any suggestions please.

I have tried all the possible options. Could not figure out since I'm new to azure.please help

Comment: Are [rn, rn1, rn2] column names or row ids?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, col, when, floor
data = [(None, 200, 1000), (2,300,400), (None, 300,500)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("rn","rn1","rn2")
>>> df.select("*").show()
+----+---+----+
|  rn|rn1| rn2|
+----+---+----+
|null|200|1000|
|   2|300| 400|
|null|300| 500|
+----+---+----+
df.select( df.rn, 
 when( 
  df.rn.isNull() , # condition
  floor(rand()*1000) # true value
 ).otherwise(
  df.rn1 # false value
 ).alias("rn1") ).show()
+----+---+
|  rn|rn1|
+----+---+
|null|545|
|   2|300|
|null|494|
+----+---+
```

Rinse and repeat for rn2.